# Sending base64 string via socket c#

Tags: c#, sockets, base64

I'm trying to send base64 encoded image.

Client code:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        IPEndPoint ipEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(ip), port);
        client = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
        client.Connect(ipEndPoint);
        Bitmap printScreen = new Bitmap(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height);
        Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(printScreen as Image);
        g.CopyFromScreen(0, 0, 0, 0, printScreen.Size);
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
        printScreen.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
        client.Send(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Convert.ToBase64String(ms.ToArray())));
        client.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
    }
```

Server code:

```
const int BUFFER_SIZE = 2048;
static byte[] buffer = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
static void ReceiveCallback(IAsyncResult AR)
    {
        Socket current = (Socket)AR.AsyncState;
        int received = current.EndReceive(AR);
        if (received > 0)
        {
            s += Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer);
            current.BeginReceive(buffer, 0, BUFFER_SIZE, SocketFlags.None, ReceiveCallback, current);
        } else
        {
            Console.WriteLine(s.Length);
            var bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(s);
            using (var imageFile = new FileStream("test.jpg", FileMode.Create))
            {
                imageFile.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
                imageFile.Flush();
            }
            s = "";
        }
    }
```

But the picture is often not transmitted.
Usually this error occurs:
"The input data is not valid Base-64 string".

How to solve this problem?
Big thanks!

Comment: Why?  Base64 is larger than just sending the bytes it encodes.

Comment: Why on Earth would you send base64 when you can send the raw binary data instead?

Comment: I know. Just specific task.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`received` tells you *how many bytes in the buffer are currently valid*. The overload of `GetString` you're using converts *all* bytes in the buffer.

You can switch to passing explicit index and count:

```
s += Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer,0,received);
```

Note, also, that this technique you're using *isn't* generally safe, but should be for the base-64 subset of characters. Not all UTF-8 characters occupy a single byte and TCP offers no guarantee that you won't only get *part* of a character returned by one call of `Receive` whilst the remaining bytes of that character would be delievered (hopefully<sup>1</sup>) by the next call.

(And Matthew's comment about this all being rather odd since you could just send the bytes directly, too)

---

<sup>1</sup>I don't mean here that the bytes will be lost. Merely that there are few guarantees offered here so you're not guaranteed that the next call will receive *all* of the remaining bytes for the character.

Comment: It works in the OP's example since base64 only uses ASCII characters, but in general you should't decode the UTF-8 data on each receive, make sure you have finished receiving all of the UTF-8 bytes first, THEN decode at one time (unless you use a streaming decoder that you can push bytes into as you receive them - the `Encoding` class is not a streaming decoder). In the OP's example, the EOF for the data is a disconnect, so append the received bytes as-is to a growing `byte[]` buffer or stream, then call `Encoding.UTF8.GetString()` on that buffer/stream only when disconnect is reached